# При скролле перед изображением мелькает белый фон

Tags: css

День добрый задавал уже примерно такой вопрос, но суть проблемы оказалась другой.Опишу-на странице есть несколько фоновых изображений для секций.Когда скролишь страницу, то на доли секунды вместо изображения появляется белый фон, и лишь потом все становится нормально и его занимает изображение.Думал, что проблема в том, что изображения не маленькие и браузер просто не успевает их загрузить.Сделал предзагрузку изображений.Но даже это не изменило ситуацию. Кто подскажет в чем проблема и как справится с ней?

Comment: пример кода обязателен

Comment: Пример кода выложить будет весьма проблематично, так как громозко получится..Но вот что я только что заметил - такое поведение только в Mozilla!В Chrome,Opera и IE работает нормально все..Каких-либо свойств требующих кроссбраузерных префиксов и чтобы они не были проставлены в коде просто нет.Вообще ничего не понимаю..